# how to create the way of talking as in the red room from Twinpeaks?

Tags: sound-effects, movies

When Agent Cooper listen to the people in the red room they have a distinctive way of talking. They speak forward, but it has some quality to it you hear when you play something backwards, yet it does not sound like as if you would have record yourself talking backwards.

Comment: Are you referring to the Twin Peaks TV series? You would help yourself by linking to a clip that demonstrates what you're after.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea who agent Cooper is, what the red room is, or what sound you're talking about. Is there an example on YouTube maybe? From what you've written, it is entirely possible that the actors learned their lines backwards and then filmed the scene backwards and then they reversed it on playback so it goes "forwards" but has the effect of seeming backwards. They did that for a **song** by the band Mutemath who had to learn the whole song backwards for their music video. That song is *Typical* if you want to look up the video.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9IpNxMiFIs   He starts talking at 2:25

Comment: I wish you could downvote comments.

Answer (score 1):

The actors recorded their lines then reversed them, then learned the backwards version.

Answer (score 0):

As MATTW pointed out (and according to David Sonnenschein's book) they played and spoke backwards and then reversed it.